# SchemaCrawler Java API: add new options to SchemaRetrievalOptions

Tags: schemacrawler

I'd like to be able to get columns on which the table I'm getting metadata on has constraints. In order to do that, I'd have to look up the value of the `columns` field for a `Constraint` (or, in my case, `MutableTableConstraint`), and constraints are retrieved via `table.tableConstraints` call (or, in Java, `getTableConstraints()`).

However, whether the `columns` list is actually populated seems to depend on `SchemaRetrievalOptions` (or, more precisely, on the result of a `informationSchemaViews.hasQuery(CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE)` call in method `retrieveTableConstraintsColumns` in file `TableConstraintRetriever.java` of the SchemaCrawler sources; `informationSchemaViews` seems to be constructed from `SchemaRetrievalOptions` in some way), which is constructed from the `connection` parameter of the `SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog()` method, unlike `SchemaCrawlerOptions`, which are constructed manually by the user.

SchemaRetrievalOptions depend on the particular DB that is used: if the `schemacrawler-postgresql` dependency is included, the options will depend on the contents of that `.jar` file; and that file has files like `postgresql.information_schema/CHECK_CONSTRAINTS.sql`, etc, which is where some of the retrieval options come from.

So, the question is, is there a way for me to influence, programmatically, `SchemaRetrievalOptions`, to include an option for `CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE`? Apparently the command line interface of SchemaCrawler can achieve this by using a config file, but I'm using the Java API and the `.jar` files corresponding to each DB dialect, and I can't really manually update the `.jar` with the `.sql` file containing the `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE` query that I need (I mean, for local usage I can, but not for distribution).

(SchemaCrawler version: 16.9.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the question is, is there a way for me to influence, programmatically, SchemaRetrievalOptions, to include an option for `CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE`?

There are few ways that I can think of that you can influence how constraint columns are retrieved. Here are some ideas, in no particular order:

1. If you have developed a `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or other data dictionary view query that you think is generally useful for a given database dialect, please submit an enhancement request to the [SchemaCrawler](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/issues) project on GitHub.
2. If you like, you can create your [custom database plugin](https://www.schemacrawler.com/plugins.html), bundle that in a jar, and make that jar available on SchemaCrawler's classpath.
3. You can programatically build `InformationSchemaViews`. For some example code to get you started, please see [`DatabaseInfoRetrieverTest.java`](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/master/schemacrawler-api/src/test/java/schemacrawler/crawl/DatabaseInfoRetrieverTest.java#L84-L100) on how to build them, and [`SchemaCrawlerUtility.java`](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/master/schemacrawler-tools/src/main/java/schemacrawler/utility/SchemaCrawlerUtility.java#L152-L155) for how to use them.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)